# Analytical map: how to display data of each region state wise

Tags: sapui5

[image: Analytical map sap ui5 fiori for sales data analysis]

I want to divide the country state wise as per latitude and longitude, plot a circle in each state, and also provide JSON-file accordingly.

I have used the below code:

```
this.oData = {
  regionProperties: [
    {
      "code": "DE",
      "region": "Germany",
      "Revenue": 428214.13,
      "Cost": 94383.52,
      "color": "rgb(92,186,230)",
    },
    {
      "code": "FR",
      // ...
    },
    // ...
  ]
};
```

In above code, is it possible to add sub region e.g. my country `"code": "IN"` sub region like `"IN-AP"`, `"IN-KA"`, etc..?